# different layout in rstudio viewer and html browser

Tags: r, rstudio, xaringan

I do not know if this behaviour is expected, I encounter a different layout between the Rstudio viewer and the html file opened with a standard browser (Firefox, Chrome) for the same `.Rmd` file.

**In Rstudio viewer**
[image: viewer]

**In Chrome (or Firefox)**
[image: chrome]

I am using `seal: false` to manually edit the title page.
Here is a minimal reproducible example :

````
---
title: "Title"
subtitle: "SubTitle"
author: "BVA"
date: "2018-08-22"
output:
  xaringan::moon_reader:
    lib_dir: libs
    nature:
      highlightStyle: github
      highlightLines: true
      countIncrementalSlides: false
    seal: false
---
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
options(htmltools.dir.version = FALSE)
```

# Very <br> long <br> title

## Very <br> long <br> subtitle

very tiny text
````

Versions:
Rstudio: 1.1.456
R version: 3.5.1
xaringan: 0.7 (same with 0.7.1)

Comment: Just a note that I get a consistent result (the one without italics) in both the Chrome browser and RStudio viewer. I've got the same versions of `R` and `xaringan` as you and RStudio v1.1.453.

Comment: Your code works on my machine too! there's no italics on the rstudio viewer

Comment: Thank you @Emi and @TCZhang for your comment. This is probably similar to this [rstudio thread](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/203955518-All-data-in-data-viewer-is-in-italics). Modifying the `font-family` from "Yanone Kaffeesatz" to "Droid Serif" gives 2 similar layouts. Importing another google font (Baloo Bha) does not reproduce the error (no italics).

Comment: Downloading a local version of the font corrected the italics style, but I still have different gap between `h1` and `h2`.

Comment: I have the same problem.  Could this be a Windows issue?  I'm using:
R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200), RStudio 1.1.456

Comment: I guess this is an issue with Rstudio with Windows. I still have this problem, I prefer not to use the viewer in Rstudio.